# where should I save a complex MVC application UI state?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, user-interface, frameworks

I've been having a look at several MVC frameworks (like rails, merb, cakephp, codeignitier, and similars...)

All the samples I've seen are basically plain and simple CRUD pages, carrying all the infr needed in the querystring and the posted field values.

I've got a couple of apps made with some sort of framework built with classic asp.

This framework handles some CRUD stuff a little more complex than the examples I found.

Something like master-detail, filtering by example, paging, sorting and similars.

I have a controller class that it's just a finite state machine, that goes thru diferent states (like new, browse, filter, show, etc.), then performs the appropiate action depending on the event raised and finally retrieves the neede info to the calling page.

To achieve this I have several hidden inputs to keep the state of the web page (like current id, filter criterias, order criterias, previous state, previous event, well, you get the idea)

What do you think would be the finnest approach to achieve this kind of funcionality?

hidden inputs built in the view and used from the controller??? (I guess that would be the equivalent of what I'm doing right now in classi asp)

--

(added in response to tvanfosson)

basically, my question refers to the third category, the context-dependent setting (in respect to the other two categories I agree with you) the info I was storing in hidden fields to store them on the querystring, I guess that when you click on the "next page" you include everything you need to save in the querystring, right? so that piece of query string gets appended in each and every link that performns some kind of action...

I'm not sure, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using the querystring instead of hidden inputs???

Comment: What state do you keep that can't be transferred to the URL as path parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use different strategies depending on the character of the actual data.  Things that are preferences, like default page size, I keep in a Preferences object (table) that is associated with the current logged in user and retrieve from there when needed.

Persistent settings associated with the current logon, like filter settings for a page, are stored in the user's session.  Generally these are things that if a user sets them in the current session they should remain sticky.  I think filter settings and visibility are like this.  If I filter a list, navigate away from it to drill down into a particular item, then come back to the list, I want my filter settings to be reapplied -- so I make it part of the session.

Context-dependent settings -- like the current sort column or page number, are controlled using query parameters.  Paging and sort controls (links) are built with the appropriate query parameters to "do the right thing" when clicked and pass any necessary query parameters to maintain or update the current context of the control.  Using the query parameters allows you to use an HTTP GET, which is bookmarkable, rather than a POST.  Using hidden form parameters makes it much harder for the user to save or enter a URL that takes them directly where they want to go.  This is probably more useful for sorting than it is for paging, but the principle applies equally.