# Where to put View State like selections in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model, controller, selection

In MVC the model contains the data and logic of the domain, the view displays information to the user and offers widgets for interaction like buttons and the controller handles input like button presses.

But where does the state of the view belong to?

For example if you have a chess game you might want to keep track of which figure is selected and which fields are highlighted (you might want to highlight possible moves).

I read about presentation model http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html which is one way of doing it.

I can think of other ways to do it:

- using a second model, which only saves selections and highlights
- putting this information into the view (but then we have some kind of logic in the GUI)
- putting it into the controller (but then we need to manually sync the view with the controller state)
- wrapping the domain model (or inheriting from it) and add selection and highlights to the other data (this somewhat is presentation model)

But what is the "normal" way of doing this in mvc (if there is such a thing as a normal way), or which way do you use or recommend?

Comment: A similar question has been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443910/where-should-i-save-a-complex-mvc-application-ui-state

Comment: thx for the link. But this thread is highly web specific. I'm mainly targeting desktop environments, in which I e.g. don't use sessions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the view shouldn't really have a state. It should display whatever the controller tells it to display. If you want to know which chess-piece is selected you track that in the controller, and the controller will pass the view which squares are valid through the view-model.

The reason for keeping the selected piece and so on in the controller is because it's part of the game-state, which in turn is part of the business logic. Business logic belongs in the controller. I assume there's a view-model because there should always be a view-model unless it's equivalent of the model itself. In most application it's not equivalent, and without a view-model you lose encapsulation, increasing coupling between the view and the controller, and makes the whole thing much more open to change.

Comment: I agree, that a view should not have a state. But why the selection belongs into the controller? (I'm not saying that it is a bad idea, but I don't really know, why it fits there best). And you seem to assume that there is a view model, which would be more or less the same as the presentation model. How is this view model implemented? Is it a wrapper around the domain model?

Comment: Haven't had time to log in here for a while, but I edited the response to answer the questions.

Comment: Thx for your help! One more question: How do you recommend me to implement the view model? Should I wrap the domain model and have access methods which forward data from the domain model and have additional methods for the view specific states?

Comment: That's a really hard question to answer without knowing more :) In general, the controllers job is to grab the relevant parts of the model, perform logic on it in order to get the data representation the view requires. In the chess example you mentioned, it would grab a representation from the model in a way optimized for calculating, convert it to a representation suited for rendering and together with the possible moves (calculated by the controller) that representation would be the view-model. Remember: views need to be very skinny, all logic needs to be in the controller.